# Multi data filter problem: second filter neglect first filter. How to solve it?

Tags: vb.net

In my simple LMS project, i filter two columns,first column with "LIKE" condition and second column with "NOT LIKE" condition at the same time. The first filter works fine and the second filter, filter well but neglect the first filterd data. I want to filter data among firstly filtered.How to filter filterd data using Both like & not like conditions? I used AND instead of OR But Unsuccessful. This is the code i used

```
Private Sub combobox4_TextChange(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles combobox4.TextChange

    If combobox1.Text = "Added Date" And withoutButton1.Checked Then
    BooksBindingSource.Filter = String.Format("catagory LIKE '%{0}%' OR Medium Not LIKE '%{0}%'", combobox4.Text)
    End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Think about the truth table for Or T Or T -> T , T Or F -> T, F Or T -> T, F Of F -> F.

Comment: Dear  Mary, can you give an example codes Please!